# Freemarker "has_content" builtin causing unexpected error

Tags: java, freemarker

I'm trying to use `has_content` to check whether a map property is non-empty before testing it as a boolean, because the data model (for reasons that are painful and tedious) can sometimes populate the field with an empty string instead of a Boolean.

However, when I try

```
<#if (mecflag?has_content && mecflag)>
```

(meaning, I think, "if the variable is not empty and if it's Boolean `true`), I get an error. The error says that Freemarker doesn't like the fact that `has_content` isn't a camel-case identifier. That seems really weird.

I'm using what I think is the current stable Freemarker, 2.3.25.

The error text:

> Naming convention mismatch. Identifiers that are part of the template language (not the user specified ones) must consistently use the same naming convention within the same template. This template uses camel case naming convention (like: exampleName) estabilished by auto-detection at line 37, column 121 by token "upperCase", but the problematic token, "has_content", uses a different convention.

Answer (score 1):

Well that didn't take long.

Apparently, Freemarker can work with *either* camel-case or "_" versions of the builtin names. Thus, `?hasContent` works as well as `?has_content`. The documentation is somewhat inconsistent.

So: if you get the "Naming convention mismatch" error, check your use of `?built_in` versus `builtIn` across the template file and choose one or the other.

Comment: Yes, but doesn't the error message that you have quoted in your question tells the same? Also, can you tell where's the documentation inconsistent regarding this?

Comment: @ddekany well I found `has_content` in the documentation written like that - `has_content`. I already knew about `?upperCase` etc. At a point in time when I had no idea that Freemarker would accept both `upper_case` and `upperCase` or `has_content` and `hasContent`, no the error message was not at all helpful. I'm not sure how the documentation could be improved.

Comment: @ddekany that said, I thank you for being the Freemarker maintainer. It's a great tool.